# How to configure Jupyter %configure with multiple packages?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight

I am using HDInishgt Spark 2.1 and in my Jupyter notebook I would like to load multiple spark packages.

```
 %%configure -f
    { "conf": {"spark.jars.packages": "com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0"}}
```

But when I try and do

```
 %%configure -f
    { "conf": {"spark.jars.packages": "com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark,com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0"}}
```

OR

```
{ "conf": {"spark.jars.packages": ["com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0","com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark"] 
}}
```

I get an error. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Late reply, but hopefully still helpful:

```
%%configure -f
{ "conf":  { "spark.jars.packages": "com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0,com.microsoft.azure:azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11:1.2.2"} }
```

You can also add repositories the same way:

```
%%configure -f
{ "conf":  { "spark.jars.packages": "com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0,com.microsoft.azure:azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11:1.2.2", "spark.jars.repositories": "http://nexus.internal/repository/maven-public/"} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
%%configure -f
{ "conf": {"spark.jars.packages": [ "com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0", "com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark" ] } }
```

Comment: Hi! That does not work :( Could not parse JSON object from input '{ "conf": {"spark.jars.packages": {"com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0","com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark"} }}' .. So it does need to be v

Comment: I just revised my code snippet actually getting a chance to try it on my cluster. Pay special attention the indentation, since this is Python it can be Cranky. I noticed above in your examples you have indentations, that will cause an error.

Comment: I tried this exactly as you put and got the error The code failed because of a fatal error:
 Invalid status code '400' from http://hn0-uticas.gxpz5ov2mlvejhmfv13j5dw1gd.cx.internal.cloudapp.net:8998/sessions with error payload: "Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@6db39e95; line: 1, column: 63] (through reference chain: com.cloudera.livy.server.interactive.CreateInteractiveRequest[\"conf\"]->com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.MapBuilderWrapper[\"spark.jars.packages\"])".

Comment: Which kernel are you using?

Comment: PySpark3, with out-the-box configuration from HDInsight

Comment: Odd, I just tried it again and it seemed to work. Maybe somethings not copying and pasting correctly?

Comment: Can you maybe upload a screenshot? and are you actually starting the SparkContext after launching? I can configure, but error is when i launch `sc` This is really strange! Lol